# How to disable form submit button using availity reactstrap validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I'm using reactjs with availity reactstrap validation. I want to disable form submit button when form have validation errors. Only enable submit button when there is no validation errors all email address is valid all validation passes. How can i achieve this?

This is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Row, Card, CardTitle, Form, Label, Input, Button } from "reactstrap";
import { AvForm, AvField, AvGroup } from "availity-reactstrap-validation";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Colxx, Separator } from "../../components/common/CustomBootstrap";
import IntlMessages from "../../helpers/IntlMessages";
import { loginUserAsync } from "./../../redux/auth/actions";
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: ""
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event, errors, values) {
    debugger;
    console.log(errors);
    console.log(values);
    if (errors.length === 0) {
      try {
        this.props.loginUserAsync(values, this.props.history);
      } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
      }
      //submit
    }
  }

  handleInputChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { username, password } = this.state;
    return (
      <Row className="h-100">
        <Colxx xxs="12" md="10" className="mx-auto my-auto">
          <Card className="auth-card">
            <div className="position-relative image-side ">
              <p className="text-white h2">MAGIC IS IN THE DETAILS</p>
              <p className="white mb-0">
                Please use your credentials to login.
                <br />
                If you are not a member, please{" "}
                <NavLink to={`/register`} className="white">
                  register
                </NavLink>
                .
              </p>
            </div>
            <div className="form-side">
              <NavLink to={`/`} className="white">
                <span className="logo-single" />
              </NavLink>
              {/* <CardTitle className="mb-4">
                <IntlMessages id="user.login-title" />
              </CardTitle> */}
              <AvForm
                className="av-tooltip tooltip-label-right"
                onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
              >
                <AvGroup className="error-t-negative">
                  <Label className="has-float-label">Email</Label>
                  <AvField
                    name="username"
                    type="email"
                    value={username}
                    defaultValue={username}
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    validate={{
                      required: {
                        value: true,
                        errorMessage: "This is a required field."
                      },
                      email: {
                        value: true,
                        errorMessage: "Please enter a valid email address"
                      }
                    }}
                  />
                </AvGroup>
                <AvGroup className="error-l-75 error-t-negative">
                  <Label className="has-float-label">Password</Label>
                  <AvField
                    name="Password"
                    type="password"
                    value={password}
                    defaultValue={password}
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    validate={{
                      required: {
                        value: true,
                        errorMessage: "This is a required field."
                      }
                    }}
                  />
                </AvGroup>
                <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                  <NavLink to={`/forgot-password`}>
                    <IntlMessages id="user.forgot-password-question" />
                  </NavLink>
                  <Button color="primary" className="btn-shadow" size="lg">
                    Login
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </AvForm>
            </div>
          </Card>
        </Colxx>
      </Row>
    );
  }
}
```

How can i make login button disable? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

[`AVForm`](https://availity.github.io/availity-reactstrap-validation/) has `onInvalidSubmit` props, maybe
you can do it like this

```
// Updated Answer
const Component = props => {
  const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false)
  const formEl = useRef(null)

  const handleChange = a => {
    setHasError(formEl.current._inputs.email.context.FormCtrl.hasError())
  }

  return (
    <AvForm ref={formEl}>
      <AvField name="email" onFocus={handleChange} onChange={handleChange} label="Email Address" type="email" required />
      <button color="primary">Submit</button>
      <div>{hasError ? "YES": "NO"}</div>
    </AvForm>
  )

}
```

Class Based

```
class AnotherApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.formEl = React.createRef()
    this.state = {
      hasError: false,
    }
  }

  handleChange = a => {
    this.setState({
      hasError: this.formEl.current._inputs.email.context.FormCtrl.hasError()
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AvForm ref={this.formEl}>
        <AvField name="email" onFocus={this.handleChange} onChange={this.handleChange} label="Email Address" type="email" required />
        <button color="primary">Submit</button>
        <div>{this.state.hasError ? "YES": "NO"}</div>
      </AvForm>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: So by default submit button is enabled or disabled in this example?

Comment: it will disabled, because at the first time render, your email or password would be `null`

Comment: Can you please give the complete code with class based component?

Comment: Can you please give the complete code with class based component?

Comment: Done, 
here just a bit of advice, I think you should be able to transform the functional component to class-based component or class-based component to functional component with ease.

Comment: It's working but if email address is not valid button is showing enabled

Comment: check hasError state, is it true or false. If your field still has an error, and u update the hasError state, it should be fine

Comment: hasError was false.

Comment: I've updated the answer. I've take a look into`Availity` github codebase, and 
I just realized that [Availity](https://availity.github.io/availity-reactstrap-validation/components/avform/) doesn't support your usecase, because it doesn't provide a method like `onChangeValidation`, so to hack it, use `ref` and add your handleChange method on each field with `onChange` and `onFocus` props. the handleChange method will get the hasValue props of the component and set it to your own `hasError` state, and i am sure this is not the best approach, there will be a bug i think.

Comment: OK Thanks I'll look into it.